# I'm trying to zoom to a graphic, but nothing happens?

Tags: features, query, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm trying to zoom to a graphic retuned from the query;

```
        query.OutSpatialReference = MyMap.SpatialReference;
        query.ReturnGeometry = true;
```

After this query I used `myMap.zoomTo(graphic.Geometry)` and tried to zoom to a specific extent but nothing happens.

Does anyone know why this does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what all you're passing into the query, and what the geometry of the layer you're querying might be. First, you should make sure that it does have some sort of geometry. Second, check that the geometry extent makes sense (same spatial reference, and within the map's extent).